# Run headless chrome as demon and save given links in to pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, docker, google-chrome-headless

Guys, I want to run headless chrome in docker container as demon and send a link to chrome. It should take this link and make a pdf.

I found a [good image](https://hub.docker.com/r/justinribeiro/chrome-headless/).It helps me to run chrome in background. But i still don't know how to send link and how to say chrome, please save web page as PDF.

I know how save to pdf locally, google has a [good tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

I will appreciate you for help, hope someone did it before

Comment: For me I will use PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara i heard it is dead now, or i'm wrong?

Comment: @dimatutrumov yes, with the born of chrome headless, it is no longer supported
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara thanks, will look at it, if won't find an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official selenium images. For this one your can just run something like below

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Then use a language of your choice with Selenium bindings. Below is a python example. You will need the python and selenium package installed

```
$ pip install selenium
```

Below is the code you can use to control the browsr

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.get("http://tarunlalwani.com")
driver.quit()
```

See below for more details of the selenium webdriver in Python

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Do you know how to create a pdf? I set all options for chrome but it didn't create a pdf?